# Edit a file that is exclusively checked out

Tags: visual-studio, visual-sourcesafe

I just started at a new company which uses VSS and has "Allow Multiple Checkouts" turned off. I can see that it is going to quickly become a problem getting things done here. Getting "Allow Multiple Checkouts" enabled is probably not an option.

Is there a way for me to edit the file anyway and then merge my changes (either using VSS or another tool) when the file becomes available?

Comment: Either get them to use another VCS, or look for another job. VSS is broken on so many levels, even Microsoft recommends that you shouldn't use it.

Comment: If I can't convince them to check "Allow Multiple Checkouts" I doubt that I could get them to change their VCS completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just make the file writeable (hold the shift key down when clicking the get button to get the dialog...)

Then try not to break anything when you merge your changes.

No shop I have ever worked in allows multiple checkouts because the merging process is so dangerous.

Comment: So when it comes time to check out the file in Visual Studio, will it prompt me to merge or will it just overwrite my changes?

Comment: @adam0101, that will depend on the "Replace writable files" setting on the "Local Files" tab of the SourceSafe Options dialog. The options are Default, Ask, Replace, Skip, Merge. Default is whichever of the other options is specified for that particular VSS database by the admin.

Comment: I believe the default is to prompt to overwrite.  ALWAYS back up the source file locally, because you (almost) never want it overwritten.  FWI: WinMerge is a good tool.  http://winmerge.org/

Answer (score 2):

Basically, nothing prevents you from editing the files. Usually these filese are marked read-only, but you can surely override that.
But better be very careful, because VSS would allow you to easily overwrite anyone else's changes.

There is an option in VSS Studio to make the files read-only unless you have them checked out. You might consider turning it off (though I wouldn't recommend that).

I believe, there's also an option in Visual Studio to allow editing read-only files. That is, if you try to edit an r/o file, Visual Studio will prompt you to make it writable. This is probably better, since you will not change the file accidentally.

Even better, migrate from VSS to SVN or another modern source control system.
VSS has lots of potential problems with stability, performance and so on.